# the solution of a functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functional-equations

Suppose $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a bijective  mapping such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$,can we conclude that $f(x)=f(1)x$?

I know the fact that if $f$ is continuous,the above conclusion holds.

Comment: There must  be a duplicate on this site, search for it. In particular, it is true under the very mild assumption of measurability, but in general it is not true by considering a basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$, and noting that $f$ is essentially a $\mathbb Q$ - linear map . Then we can define $f$ on the basis so this property doesn't hold.

Comment: Perhaps OP wants to assume only that the function is additive and bijective. Measurability is not clear from this.  @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: @KaboMurphy True, in that case the proposition is false, is it not?

Comment: You should not use the word 'linear'. The only $\mathbb R$ linear maps on $\mathbb R$ are of the type $f(x)=cx$ so there is nothing  to prove here. It is better to delete the word 'linear' from the question.

Comment: You are right,I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

No, it is false for the same reason which makes it false without the hypothesis of bijectivity.

Consider a Hamel basis $\{\alpha_i\}_{ i\in\Bbb R}$ of $\Bbb R$ as a $\Bbb Q$-vector space with, say, $\alpha_0=1$. Then consider the $\Bbb Q$-linear map $T$ such that:

- $T(1)=T(\alpha_0)=\alpha_{j_0}$;
- $T(\alpha_1)=\alpha_{j_1}$ where $\alpha_{j_1}$ is some element of the Hamel basis which is neither $\alpha_{j_0}$ nor $\alpha_{j_0}\alpha_1$;
- $T(\alpha_i)=\alpha_{j_i}$, where the map $i\mapsto j_i$ from $\Bbb R\setminus\{0,1\}$ to $\Bbb R\setminus\{j_0,j_1\}$ is some bijection.

Since $T$ sends bijectively a basis to a basis, it is bijective. However, $T(\alpha_1)\ne T(1)\alpha_1$ by definition.